# Currency precision not working in magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, currency

When i am sorting products in Magento, i have a priceslider to update the filter for price.

The products have a range from 0-1000 in price. Whenever I were to drag the slider, the filter would automatically set 1000 to 999.99 even though I didn't change the maxPrice handlebar.

This is a problem, as the ONE product that costs 1000, will not be displayed, if the slider is changed (even if only minPrice handlebar is changed)

However, i seem to have this sorted by changing Mage_Directory_Model::Currency.php:

```
public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

In formatPrecision 0 was changed from 2, as 0 now defines the number of decimals.

So now, when I change the minPrice handlebar, the maxPrice is 1000 - BUT the product that costs 1000 is still not displayed - even though the filter displayes that it is filtering products from xx - 1000

So my problem is:
My filter is displaying that it is filtering products from xx-1000, but the products which cost 1000 are not displayed. Why?

Regards
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

clear thid indexing table: "index_event"
and Rewrite URL table is also clear if not Rewrite URL in admin side: "core_url_rewrite"
remove file in the folder location : magento/var/locks

and do the indexing.